# Not able to login to Kubernetes Dashboard with token

Tags: kubernetes

I am new with Kubernetes. I have created the control node and wanted to add a service user to login in dashboard.

```
root@bm-mbi-01:~# cat admin-user.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system

root@bm-mbi-01:~# cat admin-user-clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system

root@bm-mbi-01:~# kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')
Name:         admin-user-token-kd8c8
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: admin-user
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 226e0ea4-9d2e-480e-8b1d-709b9860e561

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1066 bytes
namespace:  11 bytes
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVZOS02T3M2T3AwNUZhQXA3NDdJZENXZlpIU2F6UUtNdEdJNmd3MFg0WEEifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJrdWJlLXN5c3RlbSIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VjcmV0Lm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbi11c2VyLXRva2VuLWtkOGM4Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnQubmFtZSI6ImFkbWluLXVzZXIiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC51aWQiOiIyMjZlMGVhNC05ZDJlLTQ4MGUtOGIxZC03MDliOTg2MGU1NjEiLCJzdWIiOiJzeXN0ZW06c2VydmljZWFjY291bnQ6a3ViZS1zeXN0ZW06YWRtaW4tdXNlciJ9.OfRZlszXRt5AKxCumqSicPOkIK6g-fqPzitH_DjqskFxz6SzwYoDeFIPqyQ8O_6SFFgU6b-lgwiRmZtoj3dTKxr04PDl_t37KD7QTmBtX33vrW_sgq2EFbRkaiRxyTvFPjQDmo04iiyOQmlfzj67MIbgYYmem3NaTqgqx-j-SEi-CKTwVM4JyGa3GrTN7xeRfsFNSq1YOV6Yx1keyiD-gVEZiDxkBCJcdCJOM6p6q1s3cXgH1KWIDYkGXIHFX1f0tvu4xlr_-jgpSVehaAU98WN9DtgXL16ny1ckgKL1mPpBezrjVrf4k1lOSsXHWuE1cnlG9SnUIhbZ9k11HQJNtw
root@bm-mbi-01:~#
```

Used this token to login in dashboard. But after clicking in login, no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With IP, the URL is browsable but login button clicking is not working.
- Finally solved it by doing SSH local port formwarding
- Kubenetes Proxy was started by:

```
root@bm-mbi-01:~# kubectl proxy --address=10.20.200.75 --accept-hosts=.* &
```

- SSH tunnel from my local PC to bm-mbi-01 server

```
 ✘ s.c@MB-SC  ~  ssh -L 8001:localhost:8001 bmadmin@bm-mbi-01
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qXml.png)